# Stripe webhook when Standard connected account is updated

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to figure out how to be notified when a connected Standard Stripe account is updated.

In my app, when a user authorized my app to connect to their Stripe account, my app gets the account's display name from Stripe and stores it so the user knows which Stripe account they connected to my app.

When the user changes the display name, my app needs to be notified so I can update the display name in my database.

Neither of these webhooks fires when the user changes the display name:

`account.external_account.updated
account.updated`

Is there a different webhook I should be using or a different method to be notified of such changes?

Comment: any luck with figuring this out? i'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are setting up webhook endpoints specifically for Connect. You can find the Connect specific endpoints in your dashboard: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/webhooks

If you are creating your webhook endpoints via the API, then you just have to pass in the `connect: true` flag: https://stripe.com/docs/api/webhook_endpoints/create#create_webhook_endpoint-connect

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and found my error.
in fact i initially added the "account.updated" to an existing webhook,
but what i didn't realise is that the pre existing webhook was targeting "Direct" events and not "connected events". I fact a webhook cannot target "direct" and "connected" events at the same time.

Solution, i created a new webhook, and selected the option "Listen to events on Connected accounts" (this option only appears while creating the webhook).

You can see if your webhook is "direct" or for "connected" in the page that lists all the webhooks on the column "type".

I hope my explanation is clear.